# @vue/cli application build fail using my library

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I'm writing a Vue component library let's call it `my-component`,

when I download it from npm or use `npm link` to test in vue/cli application,

```
import { component } from `my-component`
```

It will fail on IE... but fine with chrome
[image]

But if I put my library's source code under my application folder,

```
import { component } from './lib/my-component/entry.js'
```

everything goes well.

Why webpack/vue-cli build differently in two ways?

Did I need extra settings to publish my component as a library?

Comment: i think that IE doesn't support some code in your library

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim what I'm confusing is that I put my lib under my application folder tree, it works on IE. I think the problem might be it didn't compile correctly when I using it as a 3rd package.